# How to use tabs to submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm creating a register page and I'm using tabs for Account details / Personal details / Company details. I've got it up and running, but ofcourse, since I load the pages, it clears the form fields.

Whats the best way to do this so it doesn't clear the form fields and let me submit it afterwards?

**Part of the JS:**

```
var containerId = '#aanmeld-tabs-container';
var tabsId = '#aanmeld-tabs';

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Preload tab on page load
    if($(tabsId + ' LI.current A').length > 0){
        loadTab($(tabsId + ' LI.current A'));
    }

    $(tabsId + ' A').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('current')){ return false; }

        $(tabsId + ' LI.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        loadTab($(this));       
        return false;
    });
});

function loadTab(tabObj){
    if(!tabObj || !tabObj.length){ return; }
    $(containerId).addClass('loading');
    $(containerId).fadeOut('fast');

    $(containerId).load(tabObj.attr('href'), function(){
        $(containerId).removeClass('loading');
        $(containerId).fadeIn('fast');
    });
}
```

**HTML part**

```
<form method="post" id="aanmeldForm" name="form">
<ul class="aanmeld-tabs" id="aanmeld-tabs">
<li class="current"><a href="resources/include/tabs/accountdetails.php">Accountdetails</a></li>
<li><a href="resources/include/tabs/personal-details.php">Personal Details</a></li>
<li style="padding-right: 0px !important"><a href="resources/include/tabs/company-details.php">Companydetails</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="aanmeld-tabs-container" id="aanmeld-tabs-container">
Loading. Please wait..
</div>
</form>

<div id="aanmelden-functies">
<div class="aanmeldbtn-container">
<input type="submit" id="goAanmelden" name="goAanmelden" class="button green" value="Aanmelden" /> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using $.load() which will load a fresh content each time the user clicks the tab. You have plenty of options:

1 - Serialize the current form input on tab click into sessionStorage.

```
$(".tab").on("click", function(){
    sessionStorage.formData.firstTab = $("form.firstTabForm").serializeArray();
    //and on goes to the other tab's form.
})
$("form").on("submit", function(){
    var data = sessionStorage.formData;
    console.log(data);
    $.post(url, data, function(result,status){
        console.log(result);
    })
    return false;
})
```

2 - Divide your form into sections and load it all up and hide it using css, and instead of using `$.load()`, you can use `$.show()`. This will preserve each user input without having to use any sessions etc.

Hope this helps.